# linking django apps on different ports to subdomains

Tags: django, dns

I have two django applications running on ports 8000 and 8001.
I want to connect two subdomains to these sites.
In my DNS configuration, would it be ok to create something like this?

```
app 1: create an ANAME record and point to x.x.x.x:8000
app 2: create an ANAME record and point to x.x.x.x:8001
```

This is the solution that comes to mind when i think about it.
I haven't actually tried this and don't know if it will even work.
If there's a better way, i would be glad to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want both of them to run on port 80 (or 443 for https)? You can do that using virtual hosts on apache (called server blocks in nginx)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample